# How to control version number in Perforce?

Tags: version-control, perforce

I want to have auto-generated version number in format of 'x.x.x' or something similar to 'git tag' in Perforce. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not aware git tag could produce automatically a version number.
You may allude to [`git describe`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122424/build-sequencing-when-using-distributed-version-control)

RCS can be a way to [store, and then display the version](http://maillist.perforce.com/pipermail/perforce-user/2005-May/015306.html), not to generate one.

Version number schemes [are many](https://blog.codinghorror.com/whats-in-a-version-number-anyway/) (p4 [uses its own](http://blog.perforce.com/blog/?p=665)), plus labels need to be [cleaned up once in a while](http://blog.perforce.com/blog/?p=187).
You will need some kind of script to generate one (the followinf comes from the p4 mailing list):

> For the dweeb who insists that "every last change requires a new version stamp" I'd suggest the following:  [Warning: this is Perforce-centric.]
>
> 1. Your makefile could generate version.h by running a script that
>      does something like this:

```
CHANGENUM=`p4  changes  -m1 -s  submitted //depot/main/...#have  |  cut  -f2  -d' '`
echo "#define VERSION    \"main codeline to change #$CHANGENUM\"  " > $SRC/include/version.h
```

> 2 . Then you do a build and the version string (for anything that 
>   references `VERSION`) is automatically correct.
>   Of course, I'd do this `version.h` trick for "official builds" and 
>   "overnight  builds" and make the default `version.h` that developers use have a hard-coded string to the effect of "build from main codeline but not official - do not 
>   deploy".

---

With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), "git p4" does a better job with RCS.

See [commit 1ec4a0a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ec4a0a356f73ef0ab57d3903bd6667942a7052c), [commit 38ecf75](https://github.com/git/git/commit/38ecf75244c4cab93ecb201afff8980c29f56ce8), [commit cd1e0dc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd1e0dc47a5ab1520b823d051d23f60c89072349) (14 Feb 2020), and [commit 4935c45](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4935c458c2ef301d720980eb94de4b631fe47128), [commit aa8b766](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aa8b766a1393070fc85a585b875a4a4f34a08573), [commit 9f59ca4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f59ca4d6afc69aec09eeec10e823222f4d7507b), [commit 6b602a2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6b602a2f97bbf27c8858643efeabce23195414cb) (11 Feb 2020) by [Ben Keene (`seraphire`)](https://github.com/seraphire).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5f2ec21](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5f2ec211f629f5b1d9a85e924946ae2079fa96f7), 22 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`git-p4`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ec4a0a356f73ef0ab57d3903bd6667942a7052c): add RCS keyword status message
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ben Keene</sup>
>
> During the p4 submit process, `git-p4` will attempt to apply a patch to the files found in the p4 workspace.
>   However, if P4 uses RCS keyword expansion, this patch may fail.
>
> When the patch fails, the user is alerted to the failure and that `git-p4` will attempt to clear the expanded text from the files and re-apply the patch.
>   **The current version of git-p4 does not tell the user the result of the re-apply attempt after the RCS expansion has been removed which can be confusing**.
>
> Add a new print statement after the git patch has been successfully applied when the RCS keywords have been cleansed.

Comment: Thanks, VonC. What I am dealing with is not a C/C++ project, it's just a bunch of documents(I'll tar them with version number periodically). But I guess the basic idea is the same. I am going to create a VERSION file and use your script to update it. 

I just get another two questions: 
1. Where should I put this VERSION file? If I update VERSION file, I guess the CHANGENUM changes again; 
2. In this way, I get no guarantee to trigger this script to update VERSION file automatically, right? (There are couple of guys who can reach and change the contents of this folder)

Comment: @aXqd: the idea is indeed the same, for any language. The usual place for such a file is the root directory, but any other place *defined by convention* in your project will do. The trigger is not guaranteed to *always* run this way, so some kind of change-content trigger may be better here.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my mother tongue. What I wanted to ask by my 1st question is that 'After I do a submit, I will trigger a script to update the VERSION file, but then I have to submit that new VERSION file again, so the CHANGENUM will also change again'. It seems to be a loop here.

Comment: @aXqd: usually, that kind of trigger is able to detect a submit of just one file (the `VERSION` one)... and will not do anything in *that* case.