# Versioning assemblies built off source code stored in a DVCS

Tags: build, assemblies, versioning

What I'm up to is to have an ability to tell a changeset which was used to build an assembly.

With Subversion it's all nice and simple: embed repository revision number straight into assembly version (like `1.0.5873` with `5873` being revision number).

DVCSes, however, do not have reliable human-readable revision numbers but they do have changesets which are long hexadecimal strings. Those obviously don't fit into any version number.

So the question is: what's the current best practice to version such assemblies?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you would use `git describe` to get that kind of human-readable information.

As illustrations, see:

- "[Moving from CVS to git: $Id:$ equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384108/moving-from-cvs-to-git-id-equivalent/385520#385520)"
- "[Build sequencing when using distributed version control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122424/build-sequencing-when-using-distributed-version-control/124747#124747)"
- "[what is the git equivalent for revision number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120001/what-is-the-git-equivalent-for-revision-number/4120179#4120179)"